# PostgreSQL:How to select cluster with one specific speciality?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

Assume I have a table with 2 columns:

```
Col1 Col2
 a    x
 a    y
 a    z
 b    x
 c    y
```

I want to select the col1 values which have a particular value in col2 (such as "only 'x'", "only 'y'", or "only 'x' and 'y'").

For example, if I want to select col1 values which do not have col2 value 'z', the result should be:

```
Col1
 b
 c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the nice [@a_horse_with_no_name provided sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543086/131874) and the handy [`bool_*` aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). [Code Wall](http://rextester.com/EXWXJC1024)

Not `z`

```
select c1
from t
group by c1
having not bool_or(c2 = 'z')
;
 c1 
----
 c
 b
 e
 d
```

Only `x`

```
select c1
from t
group by c1
having bool_and(c2 = 'x')
;
 c1 
----
 b
 d
```

Must have `x` and `y` and nothing else

```
select c1
from t
group by c1
having bool_or(c2 = 'x') and bool_or(c2 = 'y') and bool_and (c2 in ('x','y'))
;
 c1 
----
 e
```

At least `x` and `y`

```
select c1
from t
group by c1
having bool_or(c2 = 'x') and bool_or(c2 = 'y')
;
 c1 
----
 a
 e
```

Comment: Thanks! It was an old project and i did find a temporary solution but now this make it work beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to select col1 values which do not have col2 value 'z'*

```
select distinct t1.col1
from the_table t1
where not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1 
                    and t2.col2 = 'z');
```

> *such as "only 'x'"*

is however a bit different:

```
select col1
from the_table
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 1
  and min(col2) = 'x'
  and max(col2) = 'x'
```

"Only x" can also be done using Postgres boolean aggregate functions:

```
select col1
from the_table
group by col1
having bool_and(col2 = 'x');
```

> "only 'x' and 'y'"

This can either be read as "*at least x and y" (but other values are allowed as well). Then this would be:

```
select col1
from the_table t1
group by col1
having array_agg(col2 order by col2) @> array['x','y'];
```

With standard SQL the above would be something like this:

```
select col1
from the_table
where col2 in ('x','y')
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 2;
```

If "*only 'x' and 'y'*" means **exactly** those two, then this can be done comparing the array using `=` instead of using the "contains" operator.

```
select col1
from the_table t1
group by col1
having array_agg(col2 order by col2) = array['x','y'];
```

The `order by` for `array_agg()` is important, because `{'y','x'}` is a different array then `{'x','y'}`

This can also be expressed using the boolean aggregate:

```
select col1
from the_table
group by col1
having bool_and(col2 in ('x','y'))
   and count(distinct col2) = 2;
```

With standard SQL this "exactly those two" gets a bit more complicated:

```
select col1
from the_table t1
where col2 in ('x','y') 
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 2
  and count(distinct col2) = (select count(*) from the_table t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/BQZX64681